# Cryptographically correct way to roll a giveaway winner

Tags: randomness

I'm looking to create a fair selection of a giveaway winner, but I am versed enough in cryptography theory to determine if the below would hold up to public scrutiny if published on github.

The reason I am not using random.choice is for a "suspense" factor, where participants will be removed one by one until only one is left. I first shuffle the list, then pick random participant entries to remove.

Can someone who is well versed on this topic maybe give me some pointers or tell me I am doing it completely wrong?

```
from Cryptodome.Random import random

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Initialize object."""

        self._participants = {}

    def roll(self) -> List[str]:
        winners = []
        logs = []

        for participant, entries in self._participants.items():
            for _ in range(entries):
                winners.append(participant)

        random.shuffle(winners)
        while len(winners) > 1:
            remove_entry = random.randint(0, len(winners) -1)
            del winners[remove_entry]
   
        return logs

    def add(self, name: str, entries: int):
        """Add an entry."""
        self._participants[name] = entries
```

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. I don't see that this is on-topic ( see [help/on-topic]) for our site. Though randomness is important in Cryptography, where the cryptography fits into the question is not clear.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong :( , but I thought "Cryptographically secure (pseudo-)random number generation and entropy" summed it up. I'm using shuffle and random number generation and I don't want to reduce entropy.

Comment: I am not using Python's builtin random library. Please read my code snippet above and kindly refer to https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html . Which clearly states it is specifically designed for cryptographic operations.

Comment: Re.: _"I first shuffle the list, then pick random participant entries to remove."_  If the shuffle is random (truly?) then just remove the 1st entry, repeating the shuffles till only one is left.

Answer (score 0):

It looks mostly sound.

Why are you returning `logs`?
It is initialized to `[]` but never written to after that.

Are you aware of [`Crypto.Random.random.sample(population, k)`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/random/random.html#Crypto.Random.random.sample)?

Comment: The participants will be removed one-by-one the `random.choice` isn't better?

Comment: @kelalaka, please read over my post yet again. I very clearly state the reason why I am not using random.choice.

Comment: @cisnjxqu, oh, the logs = [] is cruft. I stripped down my code before posting and sadly forgot the logs variable. I'm very well aware of the Crypto.Random.random.sample(population, k), thanks :)

Comment: random.choice will work fine once you shuffle the list.

Comment: Why shuffle? It will return a random item either way.

Comment: Well, if the event is observable a new shuffle can increase the trust (!), as in the lotteries. Nothing more